# Using a ViewAnimator with a glSurfaceView does not animate

Tags: android

I have a ViewAnimator setup to go through a few normal views (buttons, text, etc) and then to a glSurfaceView.  When animating between the normal views it behaves as expected, however when trying to flip to the glSurfaceView it just appears.  Perhaps it is not possible to animate a glSurfaceView.

Here is how I setup the ViewAnimator

```
<ViewAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >    
    <include android:id="@+id/first"  layout="@layout/mainmenu" />
    <include android:id="@+id/second"  layout="@layout/otherscreen" />
    <include android:id="@+id/third"  layout="@layout/glview" />
</ViewAnimator>
```

Here is the problematic glSurfaceView

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView 
                        android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

How I setup the views in code

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    glSurface = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.glsurfaceview);
    renderer = new Renderer(this);
    glSurface.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Beyond that I just use showNext() and showPrevious off the ViewAnimator, and it works great, until I try and switch to that glSurfaceView.  Thanks for any input, i've been banging my head on this for longer than I would care to admit :)

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceViews cannot be animated like other views. It is just not supported.

Comment: Dam, well I wish I would have ran across that bit of information in the documentation, thanks for the tip.