# How to animate a GLSurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, animation, glsurfaceview

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936469/using-a-viewanimator-with-a-glsurfaceview-does-not-animate). But it seems that a GLSurfaceView can be scrolled by `scrollBy`, so is it possible to apply 3D transition(flipping) in ApiDemos/Rotate3DAnimation or something like that on a GLSurfaceView?

Part of the source code of ApiDemos/Rotate3DAnimation is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
    float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

    final float centerX = mCenterX;
    final float centerY = mCenterY;
    final Camera camera = mCamera;

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

    camera.save();
    if (mReverse) {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * interpolatedTime);
    } else {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));
    }
    camera.rotateY(degrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
}
```